# Robot moves sideways in RVIZ ROS

Tags: ros, odometry, gazebo, rviz

I'm using robot_localization to fuse odom, imu and gps data on a [husky robot](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Husky). After fusion, the robot now moves forward in gazebo but sideways in rviz.

I found [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/18806/robot-moving-sideways-in-rviz-ros/18903#18903). But the suggested solution didn't work for me.

How can I sync husky's movement in both gazebo and rviz in the same direction?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, imraj. How *is* your robot defined? How is your scenario configured?

Comment: @Chuck It's the husky robot and I'm using the original robot description files which can be found at https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/kinetic-devel/husky_description

Comment: What is the fixed frame assigned to in RViz?