# Mobile robot moves sideways in Rviz, but properly in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, mobile-robot, wheeled-robot

I am currently simulating a mobile robot, and I control its movements using the teleop keyboard node. Upon loading the robot model in both Gazebo and Rviz, the initial orientation appears consistent in both environments. However, when I initiate movement, I encounter a discrepancy in behavior.

In Gazebo, the robot moves along the y-axis, aligning with the expected motion based on wheel rotation. However, in Rviz, as I start moving the robot, it unexpectedly moves along the axis, which is the axis of rotation of the wheels.

Here are images illustrating the issue:

**Rviz Visualization:**
[image]

**Gazebo Visualization:**
[image]

As you can see, robot moves along the y axis in Gazebo, whereas it moves along x axis in Rviz. There was a similar question [previously](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/18806/robot-moving-sideways-in-rviz-ros),Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the specific changes needed in the URDF from that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your answer and previously mentioned answer it seems that you have to rotate some elements.

According to [REP103](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) front of the mobile robot should be aligned with X-axis. So to fix it, you have to change the rotation in your URDF file. If you have all joint attached to `base_link` (all joint have `<parent link="base_link">` inside `<joint>...</joint>`, ) you have to add rotation in `<joint>` markers as
`rpy ="0 0 1.57"` instead of `rpy ="0 0 0"` which you probably have now. But without knowing the urdf file it's difficult to say if you need some other changes. But that's the start.

Comment: OH , great , thank you so much . Previously i tried rotating the rpy of the links instead of joints to 90deg,which didn't work. Rotating the joints connected to base link worked!